# Is it standard practice to pass an extra void* along with C callbacks

Tags: python, c, binding, callback

I need help convincing a 3rd party software vendor to change their APIs to pass along some user data to callbacks.

This seems to be a standard practice as I see it often wherever callbacks are used.
I'm looking for some ammunition to give to their development team to convince them to do this.

My reasoning is that I have created 1:1 Python bindings for all of their API calls (except for the ones that take a callback).
If their APIs also took a void* for user data... for example:

```
SOME_API_register_function(char* name, char* desc, void* callback, void* user_data);
```

instead of...

```
SOME_API_register_function(char* name, char* desc, void* callback);
```

This would make it much easier (or even possible) for me to create bindings for these functions.
My bindings are currently in Cython which lacks the ability to dynamically create valid C callbacks.
I believe the cffi Python library provides this ability but these bindings are a little slower in performance and I'm worried about the kind of magic they're doing to pull it off.... also I don't want to port my bindings.

The problem is, even though we're paying customers of this software, it takes a lot to get them to even acknowledge bugs let alone provide new features.  The more ammo I have the better.
Any documentation of programming guides, best practices, etc. that says to provide a void* for user data would be helpful.

Comment: FYI, cffi uses libffi to create callbacks. The underlying technique is black magic, but libffi is pretty reliable and ported to a ton of platforms, so I wouldn't worry too much about using it.

Comment: I don't think it's done often enough to be called a "standard'. Does Cython support local functions and closures? Because if it does, that could be used as a workaround way to dynamically create callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

The `user_data` field is needed if you want to register the same function multiple times. In this case, a different `user_data` would distinguish them.

This is useful in several cases:

1. The registration is related to some object, and there may be many of these (e.g. an open file). You don't want a separate function per open file.
2. You want to do basically the same thing in several registered functions, and the difference can be expressed with some values (e.g. numeric constants). In this case, it's useful to register the same function several times, and have `user_data` contain the different values.

P.S. `void *callback` is a bad definition. The type should define the callback's parameters and return type (preferably using a `typedef`).

Comment: Thanks ugoren, it does define parameters and return type.